# Getting the "[Err] 1111 - Invalid use of group function" error

Tags: mysql, group-by, mysql-error-1111

I'm currently doing this query:

```
SELECT Date_Format(M.Signupdate,"%Y-%m") as YearMonth,
SUM(IF(Count(H.Nr) >= 0,1,0)) ,
SUM(IF(Count(H.Nr) >= 1,1,0)) ,
SUM(IF(Count(H.Nr) >= 2,1,0)) ,
SUM(IF(Count(H.Nr) >= 3,1,0)) 
FROM people M 
INNER JOIN History H ON H.login = M.Login 
WHERE
M.Masteraccount = "" AND
M.logincount > 5 AND
DATEDIFF(M.lastlogin,M.Signupdate) >= 3 AND
DATEDIFF(H.EntryDate,M.Signupdate) <= 151
GROUP BY YearMonth ORDER BY YearMonth ;
```

However, I keep getting the "[Err] 1111 - Invalid use of group function" error. If I remove the SUM's it's working just fine. Does anyone have the answer for me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the alias in the `GROUP BY`.  You will need to place the `Date_Format(M.Signupdate,"%Y-%m")` in the `GROUP BY` to get this to work. Also you cannot nest aggregate functions so you will need to use a subquery to get the `count`, then use `sum`:

```
select YearMonth,
    SUM(IF(CountNR >= 0,1,0)) ,
    SUM(IF(CountNR >= 1,1,0)) ,
    SUM(IF(CountNR >= 2,1,0)) ,
    SUM(IF(CountNR >= 3,1,0)) 
from
(
    SELECT Date_Format(M.Signupdate,"%Y-%m") as YearMonth,
        Count(H.Nr) CountNR 
    FROM people M 
    INNER JOIN History H 
      ON H.login = M.Login 
    WHERE M.Masteraccount = "" AND
      M.logincount > 5 AND
      DATEDIFF(M.lastlogin,M.Signupdate) >= 3 AND
      DATEDIFF(H.EntryDate,M.Signupdate) <= 151
    GROUP BY Date_Format(M.Signupdate,"%Y-%m") 
) src
GROUP BY YearMonth
ORDER BY YearMonth;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! However, this query still hands me back the same error :(

Comment: @VincentJames see my edit, I missed the nested aggregate functions.

Comment: Thanks again. However, the "DATEDIFF(H.EntryDate,M.Signupdate) <= 151" needs to be in the HAVING section, as it uses another table, hence can't be in the sub-query?

Comment: @VincentJames the subquery is getting the `count` of the data with the `WHERE` clause, then the `sum` is applied after. It doesn't need to be in a `HAVING` the filter is still being applied in the inner query. You cannot nest aggregate functions, so you will have to use a subquery

Comment: No, that query runs like a charm.

Comment: @VincentJames The syntax should be working -- here is a demo of the `count` in a subquery and the `sum` in the outer query -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19d12/3.  Feel free to edit this demo and post your actual table structure with sample data.

Comment: I'll have a go and let you know. Thanks so far!

Comment: In the end, this one [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71ebc/1) worked like I wanted. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @VincentJames Happy to help, if any of the answers to your questions are helpful on this site, then be sure to accept via the checkmark on the of it. It will help future visitors know that the question has been answered and you get reputation for accepting.

Comment: "be sure to accept via the checkmark on the of it."? 

Accept via the checkmart on the of it? Sorry, don't get what you mean here...

Comment: @VincentJames sorry the comment got messed up, the checkmark on the left of the answer.